# button should display only if we support order's zipcode

Tags: php

**Background** :

We have online shopping site , Customer place an order & they enter **zip code** in address section....

we saved orders information in do_order table , & supported zip codes in `shippment_details` table....

[image][image]

we listed all orders in table as below image.

**Requirement** :  We want to display **support** button below the order id only if we support the zip code of that order....

**Issue** : But the Support button is displaying below the orders even if we dont support that order's zip code....

[image]

am i using the query wrong ?

```
<?php

$star="select * from shippment_details where xpressbee='xpressbee'";
$resultstar = $db_handle2->runSelectQuery($star);

if($resultstar)
    { 
       if($orderrecords[$k]["tracking_id"]=='')
       {
?>
    <input type="button" name="shipment" id="xpress" value="support" />

<?php }}
?>
```

Comment: Where are you defining whether the zip code supported or not?

Comment: @BrindhaBaskaran Thanks for reply, i used `select * from shippment_details where xpressbee='xpressbee`

Comment: What are all the details you have in "shippment_details" table? can you share the  "shippment_details" Structure

Comment: @BrindhaBaskaran please check http://prntscr.com/lnx1j1

Comment: _“But the Support button is displaying below the orders even if we dont support that order's zip code”_ - and where does your query _check_ that info for any _specific_ order …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This below code

```
<?php
$star="select * from shippment_details where xpressbee='xpressbee' and pincode='$orders_pincode_here'";
$resultstar = $db_handle2->runSelectQuery($star);
if($resultstar)
{ 
?>
<input type="button" name="shipment" id="xpress" value="support" />
<?php }
?>
```